# How do I return the index of value using a for loop and else statement?

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop

// This function returns the index of value, or -1 if not found

```
Function Integer findValue(Integer nums[], Integer size, Integer value)
Declare Integer index

For index = 0 To size − 1
   If nums[index] == value Then
      Return index
    Else
Return -1   
   End If
End For
End Function
```

Comment: Is that supposed to be Python code?

Comment: This is not Python but something like VB? And you're already providing a function, are you asking people to translate it into Python for you? Why not just use `nums.index(value)`?

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1):

In Python, there is already a built-in function for lists to get the index [`list.index`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_list_index.asp). It returns the index of the element passed if found in list

Comment: [`list.index`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) does not return -1 if the element is not found. It raises an exception.

Comment: yeah sorry i mixed it up with str.find()